# My program doesn't count of how many tickets you have with some euros as I want

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

```py
num = input ("Please enter an amount in euros:")
x = int (num)
print (x)
a = x // 500 # The operations are performed to find how many bills of each heat there is and its residue.
x = x% 500
if not a == 0: # Condition for the value of agreement only in the result of the residue in case none exists.
b = x // 200
x = x% 200
else: b = x // 200
yes no b == 0:
c = x // 100
x = x% 100
else: c = x // 100
if not c == 0:
d = x // 50
x = x% 50
else: d = x // 50
if not d == 0:
e = x // 20
x = x% 20
else: e = x // 20
if it is not e == 0:
f = x / 10
x = x% 10
else: f = x // 10
if not f == 0:
g = x // 5
x = x% 5
else: g = x // 5 # I make several conditions that allow me
if not g == 0: #Evaluate the results of each operation
h = x // 2 # immediately above.
x = x% 2
else: h = x // 2
if not h == 0:
i = x // 1
x = x% 1
else: i = x // 1

print ("There", a, "500 euro banknote (s)")
print ("There", b, "ticket (s) of 200 euros")
print ("There", c, "ticket (s) of 100 euros")
print ("There", d, "50 euro banknote (s)") # printout of results
print ("There", and, "ticket (s) of 20 euros")
print ("There", f, "ticket (s) of 10 euros")
print ("There", g, "ticket (s) of 5 euros")
print ("There", h, "currency (s) of 2 euros")
print ("There", i, "currency (s) of 1 euros")
```

For my decomposition program a number of euros in coins. When executing it performs the condition if the other also performs me.
When it goes through the penultimate cycle, it also evaluates me and shows the other. What I can do

Comment: Apply the basics of coding Python: use meaningful variable names; learn to correctly indent your code; apply the DRY principle (do not repeat yourself: use functions or loops to code repeating steps instead of copy-pasting your code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not convert your code into a working version due to a huge amount of syntax errors, so I wrote my own

```
num = int(input("Please enter an amount in euros: "))

banknotes = {
    500: "500 euro banknote (s)",
    200: "ticket (s) of 200 euros",
    100: "ticket (s) of 100 euros",
    50: "50 euro banknote (s)",
    20: "ticket (s) of 20 euros",
    10: "ticket (s) of 10 euros",
    5: "ticket (s) of 5 euros",
    2: "currency (s) of 2 euros",
    1: "currency (s) of 1 euros"
}

while num:
    max_banknote = max(list(filter(lambda y: y <= num, banknotes)))

    count = num // max_banknote
    num -= count*max_banknote
    print("There", count, banknotes[max_banknote])
```